# Comparing right and left quasi-representable bimodules

Tags: ct.category-theory, model-categories, bimodules, profunctors

Let $\mathcal V$ be your favourite (closed, symmetric) monoidal model category. To fix ideas, set $\mathcal V = \mathrm{Ch}(k)$, the category of chain complexes over a fixed commutative ring. Given a $\mathcal V$-category $\mathcal C$, a *right $\mathcal C$-module* is a $\mathcal V$-functor $\mathcal C^{op} \to \mathcal V$. A *left $\mathcal C$-module* is, a $\mathcal V$-functor $\mathcal C \to \mathcal V$. The category of (left or right) $\mathcal C$-modules has a natural induced model structure, with weak equivalences given by objectwise weak equivalences: a morphism $\varphi : F \to G$ of $\mathcal V$-modules is a weak equivalence if $\varphi_C : F(C) \to G(C)$ is a weak equivalence in $\mathcal V$ for all $C$. We denote by $\mathcal C\text{-Mod}$ the category of left modules, and by $\text{Mod-}\mathcal C$ the category of right modules.

A *bimodule* $T: \mathcal C \leadsto \mathcal D$ is simply a $\mathcal V$-bifunctor
\begin{equation}
T: \mathcal D^{op} \otimes \mathcal C \to \mathcal V.
\end{equation}
I say that $T$ is *right quasi-representable* if for any $C \in \mathcal C$ there exists $F(C) \in \mathcal D$ such that 
\begin{equation}
T(-,C) \cong \mathcal D(-,F(C))
\end{equation}
in $\text{Ho}(\text{Mod-}\mathcal D)$ (i.e. the above right $\mathcal D$-modules are weakly equivalent). Dually, I say that $T$ is *left quasi-representable* if for any $D \in \mathcal D$ there exists $G(D) \in \mathcal C$ such that
\begin{equation}
T(D,-) \cong \mathcal C(G(D), -)
\end{equation}
in $\text{Ho}(\mathcal C \text{-Mod})$.
Right quasi-representable bimodules are called *quasi-functors*, in the differential graded setting ($\mathcal V= \text{Ch}(k)$).

Now, my question is the following. Assume that $T: \mathcal C \leadsto \mathcal D$ is a *left* quasi-representable bimodule. Is there a natural way to obtain from $T$ a *right* quasi-representable bimodule $T': \mathcal D \leadsto \mathcal C$? This would be a generalisation of the analogue statement for "usual" bimodules over $\mathbf{Set}$ (profunctors). In fact, given a profunctor $T: \mathcal C \leadsto \mathcal D$ (i. e. a bifunctor $T: \mathcal D^{op} \times \mathcal C \to \mathbf{Set}$) which is *left representable*, namely for all $D$ we have $T(D,-) \cong \mathcal C(G(D), -)$ as functors $\mathcal C \to \mathbf{Set}$, we may set
\begin{equation}
T'(C,D) = \mathcal C(C, G(D))
\end{equation}
and obtain a right representable bimodule $T': \mathcal D \leadsto \mathcal C$. This works because the isomorphism $T(D,-) \cong \mathcal C(G(D), -)$ can be made functorial in $D$. How could I argue with the *quasi*-representability hypothesis?